# Regular spaces and Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

I was going through a topology lecture note and came across the concepts of regular spaces (T3 ) and Hausdorff space (T2).

I came across a statement :Every regular space is Hausdorff .

As those notes did not contain any proof for this I tried to do it .Now a regular space is one in which given any point $\ x $ and any closed set $\ V $,which does not contain $\ x $ , there exists two disjoint open subsets $\ U_1 $ and $\ U_2 $ such that $\ x $ $\ \epsilon $ $\ U_1 $ and $\ V $ $\ \epsilon $ $\ U_2 $ .

Now for this to be a Hausdorff space , for every two distinct points $\ a $ and $\ b $, we should be able to find two disjoint open sets $\ U_1 $ and $\ U_2$, such that $\ a $ $\ \epsilon $ $\ U_1 $ and $\ b $ $\ \epsilon $ $\ U_2 $. 
Now take two points in the space $\ a $ and $\ b $ in a regular space . If we can find one closed set which contains only one of the two points then we are done . If the two points belong to two different open sets in the topology then we can guarantee that we can find a closed set that contains only one of them.How to proceed if both the points belong to the same open set in the topology ?
At the same time , whether a set is open or not depends on the topology ,I can't construct an open set as per my wish in a way that it contains only  one of the two points.
What am I missing here ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing nothing: a regular space, as you defined it, does not have to be Hausdorff.

Unfortunately, the terminology is not standardized. Some people define "regular" the way you did, and define "$T_3$" to mean "regular and Hausdorff" (or equivalently "regular and $T_1$" or "regular and $T_0$"); others, unfortunately, **interchange** the meanings of "regular" and "$T_3$", so that for them "regular" includes Hausdorff and "$T_3$" does not.

You don't have to take my word for it, see the Wikipedia article on [Regular space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space).

Comment: “If (X $\tau$) is regular and $T_1$-space. it is called a $T_3 $ -space “,Morris,Topology Without Tears and $T_3 $ is called a regular Hausdorff space .Checked Wikipedia

Comment: As I said, ["Although the definitions presented here for "regular" and "T3" are not uncommon, there is significant variation in the literature: some authors switch the definitions of "regular" and "T3" as they are used here, or use both terms interchangeably."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space) What's your point? (Personally I prefer to define "regular" without Hausdorff, and use T$_3$ for regular Hausdorff space, but was explaining to the OP that not everyone agrees.)

Answer (score 2):

X={1,2,3,4} 
Topology on X be
 { X, $\phi$, {1,2} , {3,4} }.. You can check the given space is not Hausdorff under the given topology, since there exists no disjoint neighbourhoods of 0 and 1. but, it is regular.

Comment: I think you have to replace $0$ by $2$ , cause there is no such point $0$.